# Scala IDE not working properly in Eclipse Luna for Java EE

Tags: eclipse, scala, scala-ide

I've tried and re-tried to install the Scala IDE in several different ways in the Java EE specific version of Eclipse, but I just can't get it to work.

The Scala first-time configuration screen doesn't appear, I can't create Scala projects, and the Scala perspective is nowhere to be found...

I've used the Scala IDE before, and it always worked flawlessly...

Going to `Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details` I can see that the IDE is indeed installed, so why it doesn't work is beyond me...

Any help in resolving this issue?

Comment: Which version did you install? Only the nightlies have worked for me.

Comment: @Paul I've tried both the milestone and the marketplace versions

Comment: @Paul you're right about the nightly version, if you'd put it as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: You mean the nightly works? (for you)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The milestone version appears not to work with Luna. However, the nightlies do work (the nightly versions work for me (initially the worksheet didn't, but that started working with a later nightly)

Comment: I succeeded once on a second install with nightly, but then failed on a fresh install with nightly. They recognize the issue: "I can reproduce the problem now. It is only visible with the 'JEE' favor of Eclipse. The conflicting bundle is not is the 'standard' distribution."

Comment: The nightlies still fail for me sometimes (the worksheet doesn't,er,  work)- but an `eclipse -clean` gets things working agin

Answer (score 0):

I too had quite a bit of trouble getting Scala-IDE to work again after upgrading to JDK8 and Eclipse Luna (and sbt 0.13 and scala-2.11.2)

But I got this running:

First I got `~/workspace/.metadata` out of the way (moved somewhere else) so Eclipse would start fresh.  Then I also modified the `eclipse.ini` to address the disappearance of `MaxPermSize` in Java 8:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms60m
-Xmx1024m
-Xss2m
```

Finally, after starting Eclipse, use the following update site:
`http://download.scala-ide.org/sdk/lithium/e44/scala211/dev/site` (as per http://scala-ide.org/download/milestone.html#scala-ide-400-milestone-2).